# Change UITableView to UIView in Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I made the mistake of using a UITableView as the main controller of a view in Storyboards so now I want to convert it from a UITableVie to a UIView with a UITableView inside of it.

The problem is, well, XCode isn't a big fan of what I want to do. Inside my UITableView controller I changed the interface from UITableView to UIViewController but it's still no bueno inside of StoryBoard.

Storyboard refuses to let me drag a UIView into my view and put the TableView inside of it.

Any idea how to do this without scrapping everything?

Thanks!

Comment: First create a new class subclassed by UIViewController, then add its scene to storyboard. In its view, add a UITableView widget and attach an IBOutlet to file owner in .h file. For more details search for UITableView tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply copy and paste your UITableView from the UITableViewController to a new UIViewController:

[image]

Then you need to create a new custom UIViewController class file (to replace your UITableViewController) and copy and paste the programmatic control functions. You will also need to assign the proper delegates to the new UIViewController `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`. In the viewDidLoad function you must assign the new controller as the the UITableView's delegate and datasource. If that is not clear you can find many tutorials online to explain the details.

Comment: Awesome, did this and it worked relatively well and bug free. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some configs of storyboard file can be edited only when you open it in text format. For example, even when I changed the type of ViewController from UITableViewController to UIViewController in .storyboard file, and edited its .h + .m files, but the icon in storyboard was still a tableview [image] but not a view [image], and I still couldnot add items outside the table, too.

I followed this tutor, and it worked well for me: http://steve.zazeski.com/convert-a-uitableviewcontroller-to-a-uiviewcontroller/.

**In addition**, if you want to keep the tableView in your class's view, just create a "subviews" tag, then copy & paste the tableView's xml code into its body. It will look like this:

```
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="qrH-Fc-mM8">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="1000" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="BOG-Ip-6do">  *** content of your tableView ***</tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
```